# pathlib takes more time traversing directory recursively than os.walk()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I'm experimenting to determine if the `pathlib` module is an improvement over the `os` for directory traversal. To my surprise, I am getting better readings from the `os` module when compared to `pathlib`. Which is something I was not expecting. Is it because the `os` module is dumb enough to not care if the path string represents a file or a directory or a link etc? So speed vs better control?

Perhaps I am not using `pathlib` the way it should be used for this.

Here's the code:

```
import os
import sys
import pathlib
import time
import pdb

def TraverseDir(path=None, oswalk=None):

    if path is None:
        path = pathlib.Path().home()
    
    oswalk = True if (oswalk == 'True') else False

    if (oswalk == True):
        method = "oswalk"
    else:
        method = "Pathlib"

    start = time.time()

    count = 0
    with open("filelist" + '_' + method, "w+") as file:
        if (oswalk):
            for ( _, _,fnames) in os.walk(path):
                for fname in fnames:
                    count += 1
                    file.write(fname + '\n')
                    continue
        else:
            for Fullpath in pathlib.Path(path).rglob("*"):
                if Fullpath.is_file():
                    count += 1
                    file.write(str(Fullpath.name) + '\n')
                    continue

    end = time.time()
    print(f"Took {end - start} seconds with {method}, counted {count} files")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        path = sys.argv[1]
        if ((path.lower() == 'true') or (path.lower() == 'false')):
            oswalk = path
            path = None
        else:
            oswalk = sys.argv[2]
    except IndexError:
        path = None
        oswalk = None
    TraverseDir(path, oswalk)
```

Is this the most optimum way this `pathlib` should be used for traversing a directory tree? Please shed some light on this.

UPDATE1: Now that I know that `pathlib` is not a competitor (so to speak) of `os`, rather a compliment, will resort to mixing them both when need be.

Comment: "Which is something I was not expecting." Why weren't you expecting that? pathlib is not supposed to be an optimization, rather, it is provided for a much cleaner/expressive API.

Comment: This is well known (look for example [here](https://treyhunner.com/2019/01/no-really-pathlib-is-great/), the section about performance). If you _really_ need the extra speed, then go for `os.walk`, otherwise stay with `pathlib`.

Comment: Ok. May be I was unaware that `pathlib` is a complement to `os` in the sense that it provides a much more feature rich and expressive API. It is not an improvement over `os` vis-a-vis speed per se. Thank you for clearing this out

Answer (score 0):

The part that should be obvious is that pathlib is creating path objects and that takes time, vs. os.walk that is just returning the strings.